# postman- this request does not have any test

Tags: postman

I have a question I have some tests and am I using a CSV file to provide data, this CSV has a column called category I want some tests to run only when the data has the category user

this is what I have on the test

```
if(data.test_type == “happy_path” & data.category == “user”)
pm.test(“Status code is 200”, function () {
pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

else if(data.test_type == “unhappy_path” & data.category == “user”)
pm.test(“Status code is 422”, function () {
pm.response.to.have.status(422);
});
```

the tests work the way they are supposed to work when I use the runner, but when the data doesn’t have the category user there is just a blank space like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbcw9.png)

The test is working, but is there a way to not show “This request does not have any test” every time one row of the CSV doesn’t have the category user? Because there are a lot of empty tests and I want to see in the report only the test that actually did run

Comment: You're choosing not to run a test if the conditions are not met so it's factually correct. That request doesn't have a test. You could add another condition to that flow that pushes it down a different route and have a `pm.test.skip(...)` so that it shows something different in the runner.